# How can I hide page elements by default but later show them with Knockout?

Tags: html, knockout.js

I'm developing a single-page web app using Knockout and jQuery. The body of the page is divided into different `<section>`s, each of which corresponds to a certain page; the user will only see one section at once. We're using Knockout's `visible` binding to hide and show the sections as appropriate, and it works fine.

The problem is that as the page is loading--when the HTML has loaded but Knockout has not yet applied its bindings--all of the sections are visible. This lasts for less than a second, but it is unsightly. I tried to set `display: none` on the sections so that they would be invisible initially, but there's a quirk with [Knockout's `visible` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/visible-binding.html): if the expression evaluates to true, Knockout sets the CSS `display` property to whatever it would have been without Knockout.

In other words, setting `data-bind="visible: true"` will not override `display: none`. This makes sense, since there are often situations when you need to specify the display as either invisible or, say, `table-cell`, but it's annoying in my case. What's the best way to force Knockout to show my section elements?

Comment: BTW, wouldn't it be better to use `if:` instead of `visible:`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that while Knockout will not override a `display: none` set in the CSS, e.g.

```
body > section {
    display: none;
}
```

it *will* override the same style directive if it appears in the HTML itself:

```
<section style="display: none" data-bind="...">
```

Thus, the solution to my problem was to move the `display: none` from the CSS file into the `style` property. Knockout then overrode the property to display my `<section>` when I wanted it to be displayed.